# Project is not white listed when using google cloud message - GCM Service for android

Tags: android, python, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

When using GCM I get error:

`The Project 3425345631 not whitelisted`.

I'm trying to use GCM - I have created an Andorid key and a server key. I'm also following the tutorial [Getting Started with GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html#gcm-service). The problem comes when I'm trying to run the python code for the CCS server. I get the error `The Project 3425345631 not whitelisted`. I have put the project number as USERNAME in the python code, and for the PASSWORD I used the generated API key for server apps in google API, and REGISTRATION_ID has a value from the registered device (Android phone) that I want to send messages to.

Can some one please describe the entire process of setting up the CCS server for Google Cloud Messaging?

Comment: very nice tutorial here http://tech-papers.org/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications-2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [special sign-up form](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/gcm/) for CCS and user notifications, in which you supply your Google API project it. You can't use those new APIs without Google accepting your registration on that form.